# how to read a tab delimited .txt file and insert into oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, utl-file

I want to read a tab delimited file using PLSQL and insert the file data into a table.
Everyday new file will be generated.
I am not sure if external table will help here because filename will be changed based on date.

Filename: SPRReadResponse_YYYYMMDD.txt

Below is the sample file data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option that works on your own PC is to use **SQL*Loader**. As file name changes every day, you'd use your operating system's batch script (on MS Windows, these are .BAT files) to pass a different name while calling `sqlldr` (and the control file).

**External table** requires you to have access to the database server and have (at least) `read` privilege on its directory which contains those .TXT files. Unless you're a DBA, you'll have to talk to them to provide environment. As of changing file name, you could use `alter table ... location` which is rather inconvenient.

If you want to have control over it, use **`UTL_FILE`**; yes, you still need to have access to that directory on the database server, but - writing a PL/SQL script, you can modify whatever you want, including file name.

---

Or, a simpler option, **first** rename input file to `SPRReadResponse.txt`, **then** load it and save yourself of all that trouble.